# Get active users windows 10 joined azure ad, Microsoft graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, windows-10

I have some users in azure ad and some windows 10 joined devices. I want to get list of active users in windows 10(logged in with azure ad) making request to Microsoft graph, but i can't find that option.
I would appreciate any help or indication that you could give me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
Get https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/devices?$count=true&$filter=startswith(operatingSystem, 'Windows')&$expand=registeredUsers
```

With request header `ConsistencyLevel:eventual`

**Reference:**

[List devices - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/device-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)